# Building HtmlStrings in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvchtmlstring

I have an extension method that needs to return an HtmlString. The method has a loop which will build the HtmlString, however the HtmlString object has no Append method and does not allow concatenation using the + operator so I am not sure how I would build the HtmlString.

I'd like to use the StringBuilder but it doesn't have a ToHtmlString method...

Any solutions or patterns for this?

Comment: I think you should be able to build a normal stringbuilder with the HTML content and then output it wrapped in an @Html.Raw() call, would this solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks - that worked great. Will draft an answer with code for this solution.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped, no point re-inventing the wheel if there's a helper for it! :)

Comment: I prefer the answer by @swapneel as it leaves the door open for adding a RouteValueDictionary parameter to your extension method and have the relevent tag rendered in a MVC'y way. This applies whether you are rendering a single tag or a whole block of HTML.

Comment: I am not sure if I get this right so I won't post it as an answer, but how about using your StringBuilder but adding an extension method to StringBuilder ToHtmlString?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want to use [TagBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.aspx).  See also [Using the TagBuilder Class to Build HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs) like this:

```cs
// Create tag builder
var builder = new TagBuilder("img");

// Create valid id
builder.GenerateId(id);

// Add attributes
builder.MergeAttribute("src", url);
builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);
builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

// Render tag
return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
```

Answer (score 34):

Why not just build the string in a stringbuilder and then

```cs
return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the [fubu spin-off](http://htmltags.fubu-project.org/getting-started/) for creating HTML Tags. [Here is a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705294/how-to-create-nested-ul-li-tags-with-htmltags-fubumvc) that talks a bit about its usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the `ToHtmlString()` method yourself as a extension method on `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this including using the `TagBuilder`, but using `Html.Raw()` worked very well for me:

```cs
public static IHtmlString HtmlMethod(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper, Object object)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in object)
    {
        sb.Append(object.outputStr)
    }
    return htmlHelper.Raw(sb.ToString());
}
```